# How to fix Menubutton on TOP_LEFT inside HBox using

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml, scenebuilder

I am using a scene builder. I have an HBox and a MenuButton as a child inside it,

Position of my MenuButton changes when I resize my Scene.fxml. I want the Menu button to stick always to the top left corner of Hbox. How can i achieve this?

I have tried setting margin and Alignment of the button to the Top_left corner. It dosen't work.

Here is my Scene.fxml file.

```
[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="563.0" prefWidth="342.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="342.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="363.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
            <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="346.0">
               <children>
                  <MenuButton alignment="TOP_LEFT" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="56.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <items>
                      <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Standard" />
                      <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Scientifics" />
                    </items>
                  </MenuButton>
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField editable="false" prefHeight="146.0" prefWidth="342.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
      <GridPane layoutX="-2.0" layoutY="227.0" prefHeight="363.0" prefWidth="342.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="199.8">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="-" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="71.0" text="+" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="4">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="X" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="74.0" text="AC" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="4" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="9" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="5" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="71.0" text="6" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="8" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="73.0" text="\%" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="." textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font size="32.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="0" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="67.0" text="sqrt" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="74.0" text="/" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="=" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="72.0" text="1" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="2" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="3" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="72.0" text="*" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Sin" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="73.0" text="x^2" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="74.0" text="1/x" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="Tan" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="Cos" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="7" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSKLO.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewlqj.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue are not the properties/layout constraints for the `MenuButton` but the fact that the `HBox` is not allowed to grow any wider than the preferred width (`346.0`).

Change the value of `maxWidth` to `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` (=`-1`). Alternatively simply remove the attribute to the default value that happens to be `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`.

This allows the `HBox` to grow to the size of the `SplitPane` preventing a smaller sized `HBox` from being centered horizontally.

```xml
  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="342.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="363.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    <items>
        <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="346.0"> <!-- removed maxWidth here -->
           <children>
              <MenuButton alignment="TOP_LEFT" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="56.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                ...
              </MenuButton>
           </children>
        </HBox>
        ...
    </items>
  </SplitPane>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped. Hey, do you know any resource that I should look to learn this fxml better and have a good understanding like yours?

Comment: @GauravYadav For understanding fxml, basically this should be enough: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html To identify problems like this you need to know how the layouts (or controls like `SplitPane`) used work. Scenes loaded by `FXMLLoader` do not behave any different to scenes created using java code...

Answer (score 0):

I've read your question and want you to look for the alignment properties of MenuButton.
Or You can use the border Pane to align your components in four ways.

1) TOP,
2) Bottom,
3) Left,
4) Right

Comment: Well, I have tried all the properties of alignment MenuButton. It doesn't work. When I maximize the Scene.fxml, MenuButton changes its position from left to center inside AnchorPane. I want it to stick to left only.

Comment: Yes, When you use AnchorPane initially it will pick the center position for your component.

you can replace your Hbox with border pane and you will find the region TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT.

There you can place your MenuButton to the left region of borderPane.

Comment: Hei thanks for answering issue is solved ..see the above code